# EXCEL VBA code needs extra email message code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to coding and having some issues with adding an extra email message for an email reminder. The code i found is for a 60/90 day email reminder, there is one email message for both reminders. I want to route the 60 and 90 day reminder to a specific email message, not the same generic one, can anyone help me out?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendReminderNotices()
' ****************************************************************
' Define Variables
' ****************************************************************
Dim wkbReminderList As Workbook
Dim wksReminderList As Worksheet
Dim lngNumberOfRowsInReminders As Long
Dim i As Long

' ****************************************************************
' Set Workbook and Worksheet Variables
' ****************************************************************
Set wkbReminderList = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksReminderList = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' ****************************************************************
' Determine How Many Rows Are In the Worksheet
' ****************************************************************
lngNumberOfRowsInReminders = wksReminderList.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' ****************************************************************
' For Any Items That Don't Have A Date In Columns 7 or 8,
' Check To See If The Reminder Is Due.
'
' If Reminder Is Due, then Send An Email.
' If Successful, Log The Date Sent in Column 7 or 8
' ****************************************************************

For i = 2 To lngNumberOfRowsInReminders
' ****************************************************************
' First Reminder Date Check
' ****************************************************************
    If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
        If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 3) <= Date Then
            If SendAnOutlookEmail(wksReminderList, i) Then
                wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = Date 'Indicate That Reminder1 Was Successful
            End If
        End If
    Else
' ****************************************************************
' Second Reminder Date Check
' ****************************************************************
        If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = "" Then
            If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 4) <= Date Then
                If SendAnOutlookEmail(wksReminderList, i) Then
                    wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = Date 'Indicate That Reminder2 Was Successful
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Function SendAnOutlookEmail(WorkSheetSource As Worksheet, RowNumber As Long) As Boolean
Dim strMailToEmailAddress As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

SendAnOutlookEmail = False

strMailToEmailAddress = WorkSheetSource.Cells(RowNumber, 6)
strSubject = "Reminder Notification"
strBody = "Line 1 of Reminder" & vbCrLf & _
          "Line 2 of Reminder" & vbCrLf & _
          "Line 3 of Reminder"

' ****************************************************************
' Create The Outlook Mail Object
' ****************************************************************
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon "Outlook"
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

' ****************************************************************
' Send The Email
' ****************************************************************
On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
With OutMail
    .To = strMailToEmailAddress
    .Subject = strSubject
    .Body = strBody
    .Send
End With

' ****************************************************************
' Mail Was Successful
' ****************************************************************
SendAnOutlookEmail = True

Continue:
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Exit Function

' ****************************************************************
' Mail Was Not Successful
' ****************************************************************
ErrorOccurred:

Resume Continue
End Function
```

Comment: Besides removing "sorry for my noobness" Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** - this compiles with no errors:

```
Public Sub SendReminderNotices()

Dim wkbReminderList As Workbook
Dim wksReminderList As Worksheet
Dim lngNumberOfRowsInReminders As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim strSubject As String, strBody As String, strEmail As String

Set wkbReminderList = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksReminderList = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

lngNumberOfRowsInReminders = _
             wksReminderList.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lngNumberOfRowsInReminders

        If wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = "" And _
           wksReminderList.Cells(i, 3) <= Date Then

                strEmail = wksReminderList.Cells(i, 6).Value
                strSubject = "First Reminder"
                strBody = "text here..."
                If SendAnOutlookEmail(strEmail, strSubject, strBody) Then
                    wksReminderList.Cells(i, 7) = Date
                End If

        ElseIf wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = "" And _
               wksReminderList.Cells(i, 4) <= Date Then

                strEmail = wksReminderList.Cells(i, 6).Value
                strSubject = "Second Reminder!!!"
                strBody = "other text here..."
                If SendAnOutlookEmail(strEmail, strSubject, strBody) Then
                    wksReminderList.Cells(i, 8) = Date
                End If
        End If

    Next i

End Sub

Private Function SendAnOutlookEmail(strAddress As String, _
                                    strSubject As String, _
                                    strBody As String) As Boolean
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    SendAnOutlookEmail = False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon "Outlook"
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
    With OutMail
        .To = strAddress
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = strBody
        .Send
    End With

    SendAnOutlookEmail = True

Continue:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrorOccurred:
    Resume Continue
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I get a compile error when testing...strEmail =

Comment: Sorry i have no idea how to do that....i've been playing with it and now i'm getting a different error.... (Next Without For)

Comment: Just got it working, you my friend the man! Thanks for your help!